# Cloud Mask Assesment without Reference Cloud Mask

Tags: sentinel-2, research, cloudmasking

We have a cloud mask but we don't have reference data set to assess its accuracy. Without generating a reference dataset by ourselves is it possible to assess the cloud mask's accuracy??
For example; can we compare the spectral signatures of the rasters which were taken a cloud-free day and the mask applied raster? or can we look the spectral signature values correlation between 2 raster? (one is cloud-free, second is the mask applied raster?

Answer (score 1):

As far as Sentinel-2 is concerned (as suggested by the tags), reference cloud masks exist. See for instance https://zenodo.org/record/1460961#.YSyWLkw69aQ

Still with Sentinel-2, it is also possible to compare two different cloud masks methodologies by comparing the smoothness of reflectance time series. We used such a criterion to compare options in atmospheric correction [in the following reference](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/9/12/1230) .

Comment: I read almost all your papers since I was trying to compare the performance MAJA with an AI and deep learning based algorithm for my study. I was asked if there are no reference masks how can we assess the performance of MAJA masks? Can we still use the smoothness of reflectance time series for MAJA masked image and cloud-free RGB Sentinel-2 L1C(if it is available)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't come often to stack exchange. please contact me via email, you'll find my adress in my papers.